# Spacemacs move cursor using word wrap, not line breaks

Tags: spacemacs, cursor, wrapping, newlines

I would like to be able to move the cursor around using the visual buffer, but I don't want to add line breaks to the source file. I'm not sure a better way to describe it, so I got some gif examples.

Here is vscode:
[image: vscode]

Here is emacs:
[image: emacs]

Both have the same file open and I am moving around the same line of text, vscode treats the wrapped line as multiple while emacs treats it as a single. I would like to make emacs behave like vscode. I have spacemacs installed with the base setup and vim mode.

Comment: See `visual-line-mode` in the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html#Visual-Line-Mode).

Comment: @NickD I have that mode enabled already, is there some config that would allow me to use the arrow keys to move around using the visual lines?

Comment: I tried `(setq line-move-visual t)` but it didn't change anything

Comment: `right-word` or `left-word` will do it, usually bound to `C-right` or `C-left`. If you want make them the default, just change the keybindings. `line-move-visual` set to non-nil value should move by buffer lines, unless you haven't evaluated it or it's overriden by a mode/hook or whatever.

Comment: Provided you're using Emacs 23+, `line-move-visual` is what you're looking for, and it's enabled *by default*.  Try with `emacs -Q`.  If it's not working, and you're using Emacs 23 or later, then tell us what commands you're using to move up and down between lines.

Comment: @phils I have emacs 25.2.2 and I'm using the arrow keys. It looks like it might be something with spacemacs, because the setting does work with the `-Q` flag.

Comment: Not wanting to be repetitive, but what does `C-h v line-move-visual` say?

Comment: @phils the variable is set to true, but it sounds like I need to enable it in spacemacs but `spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation` has no effect.

Comment: Oh, I meant "what does it say in spacemacs?" rather than under -Q (the latter I already know :)  I'm just trying to get *confirmation* of the value of that variable in the case where you're not getting the behaviour you want.

Comment: @phils It's still `t` in spacemacs. It looks like the problem is that `<down>` need to be bound to `evil-next-visual-line` and the reverse for `<up>`. This is done on the develop branch, but spacemacs hasn't merged to master in some time.

Comment: Very good.  I think you could go ahead and write your own answer to the question at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. Emacs has the `line-move-visual` variable, but spacemacs requires `spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation` to be run instead. If you want this command to modify the bindings for the arrow keys you'll have to switch spacemacs to the `develop` branch (as of 2020-06-25). To do this, skip to step 6 below.

If that solves your problem, congratulations! I am still running elementary Hera (based on Ubuntu 18.04) and was having issues with the elpa gpg key being expired. My workaround is to install emacs26, my full process to fix the issues follows.

1. Remove and purge emacs: `sudo apt remove --purge emacs`
2. Remove config: `rm ~/.spacemacs && sudo rm -R ~/.emacs.d/`
3. Add emacs stable release PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs`
4. Install emacs: `sudo apt install emacs26`
5. Install spacemacs: `git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs ~/.emacs.d`
6. Change emacs to `develop` branch: `cd ~/.emacs.d/ && git checkout develop`
7. Start emacs: `emacs26`
8. Turn on visual line navigation `spacemacs/toggle-visual-line-navigation-on`

Voilà, visual line navigation with arrow keys on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This has no effect for me using arrow keys or emacs keybindings (C-n/p).